# Overflow:hidden showing pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use overflow:hidden on a div element so that when I resize it the text it contains doesn't overlap other elements, but when I do it my :after element dissapears too.

Here's a couple images:
[image: With overflow:hidden][image: Without overflow: hidden]
[image: resized with overflow:hidden][image: resized without overflow:hidden]

Comment: Images are always helpful, but next time would you post your code as well? It helps both people answering your question and anyone who might stumble upon your question later.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the pseudo-element is positioned outside the left edge of the `div` element, not inside.

See if you can move the pseudo-element to a different element (preferably a parent) where it won't be affected by the overflow setting on your `div`. If no suitable element exists, you may have to add a wrapper to the `div` and put the pseudo-element there.